# CETAS in SQL Server 2022

Tags: sql-server, polybase, sql-server-2022

I have followed the below steps in SQL Server 2022:

**Step 1**: Create a master key

**Step 2**:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [BlobSAS]
WITH
    IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
    SECRET   = '?sv=2021-06-08&ss=bfqt&srt=c<<>>';
```

**Step 3**:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [BlobSource]
WITH (
    LOCATION   = 'abs://<<>>.blob.core.windows.net/dummy',
    CREDENTIAL = [BlobSAS],
);
```

**Step 4**:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [CommaDelimited] WITH (
    FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
    FORMAT_OPTIONS (
        FIELD_TERMINATOR = N',',
        STRING_DELIMITER = N'"',
        FIRST_ROW = 2,
        USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = True
    )
)
```

**Step 5**:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Demo WITH (
    LOCATION    = '/Test',
    DATA_SOURCE = [BlobSource],
    FILE_FORMAT = [CommaDelimited]
)
AS
SELECT
    2 AS C1,
    2 as C2
```

I am getting this error:

> Access check for '`CREATE/WRITE`' operation against
> '`abs://<<>>.blob.core.windows.net/dummy/Test`' failed with `HRESULT = '0x80070005'`

Note: All permissions was provided while generating SAS

[image]

I also tried key route :

```sql
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [BlobKey] WITH
    IDENTITY = '<<>>',
    SECRET = '<<>>';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [BlobKeySource] WITH (
    LOCATION   = 'abs://<<>>.blob.core.windows.net/dummy',
    CREDENTIAL = [BlobKey]
);
```

and when executing the below statement via sys admin account

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Demo WITH (
    LOCATION    = '/Test',
    DATA_SOURCE = [BlobKeySource],
    FILE_FORMAT = [CommaDelimited]
)
AS
SELECT
    2 AS C1,
    2 as C2
```

I'm getting the error:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Cannot find the `CREDENTIAL` 'BlobKey', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: What is "CETAS"?

Comment: Create external table as select >> CETAS in MSFT SQL server 2022

Comment: Have you tried recreating your shared access signature without the `?` character at the beginning? The SAS URI presented in the Azure GUI is usually a complete https:// URI and the `?` character is just a delimiter between the container name/path and the SAS Token itself.

Comment: The screenshot at [SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview#sas-token) is incorrect by including the `?` character. See instead [Creating a Credential using a SAS Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-credential-transact-sql#d-creating-a-credential-using-a-sas-token)... _The SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE secret should not have the leading `?`._

Comment: hey @AlwaysLearning thanks for your inputs but even with or without the ? character I am getting the same error of access check

Answer (score 0):

I've just had loads of issues trying to do the same. Please your code does all of the following: (It looks like 2 & 3 are fine, but it may be a useful reference for others).

- Shared access signature is generated for the **container** and not the storage account (Note this is different from how you would set it up in Azure Synapse SQL DW Pools)
- No Type specified in the external data source (sometimes documentation states HADOOP or BLOB_STORAGE)
- the location must be an `abs://` link and not `adls://`.